# My mouse changes themes when over menus

Tags: mouse-pointer

My mouse pointer changes from white, with a black outline, but when I have my mouse over the top bar or the side it changes to a black mouse, with a white outline. The mouse also is slightly bigger and curvier. This is with ubunu 15.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you've installed that "white with black outline" theme yourself.

If you did, then you need to get the theme to work across *all* programs:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
```

Select your chosen theme.

Reboot, or log out and log back in.

Comment: Wait, Ubuntu requires administrator privileges to *set a mouse pointer theme*?