# How can I set the Gnome 3 cursor theme consistently for one user?

Tags: gnome, themes

Under Ubuntu 16.04, using Gnome 3, I have installed and selected the [Paper](https://snwh.org/paper) cursor theme. When the mouse is over the top bar, it respects this theming. When it is over the title bar of a Gnome application, it does not.

[Other solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708624/my-mouse-changes-themes-when-over-menus) to this problem suggest running `sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme` and selecting the theme to make it consistent across all applications. But this will presumably change the theme for all users, and requires superuser access.

How can a user without superuser access set a cursor theme for only themselves?

---

Here's an example of the problem. When the mouse is over the top bar, it uses the Paper theme:

[image: Mouse theme being good]

When it's over a title bar it does not:

[image: Mouse theme being bad]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Wayland instead of X.org when logging in Ubuntu 17.10.